# How To Identify Error Points For Stack Overflow Is Forcing Device Reset Error In MikroC Code

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

**Description:**

I tried to make a circuit using PIC18F4550 Microcontroller and MikroC Programming Language. This is my program sequence.

- There are 20 schedules to choose and each schedule have 6 timing values.
- This schedule number store in the first EEPROM and other times data store from 10 to 129 EEPROM memory. (6 timing values x 20 schedules and starts from 10 memory)
- The user can choose one of the schedules and can edit times of each schedule.
- When a user selects a schedule those times values for outputs delay.
- Data show on LCD Display
- This has 6 Inputs. (Settings (B1), Up (B2), Down (B3), Enter (B4), Reset (B5), Test (B6), Proximity (B7)

***I just add this only for understand the code.***

**Code:**

This is my program for this sequence in MikroC language. Still not finished it.

```
     // LCD module connections
    sbit LCD_RS at RD0_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN at RD1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4 at RD4_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5 at RD5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6 at RD6_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7 at RD7_bit;

    sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD6_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD7_bit;
    // End LCD module connections
    unsigned short shedno=0,i=0,shedc=0,streg,lsreg,rang,x,ed,edi;
    unsigned count=0,reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6,sttime=1000,editno1=0,editno2=0,editno3=0,editno4=0,editno5=0,editno6=0;
    char shednon[4]="",countn[6]="",stregn[4]="",lsregn[4]="",regval[6]="",ntrel1[6]="",ntrel2[6]="",ntrel3[6]="",ntrel4[6]="",ntrel5[6]="",ntrel6[6]="";


     void findshed(short sno){
        shedno = EEPROM_Read(0x00);
        shedno = 256 - shedno;
        shedno = shedno + sno;
        ByteToStr(shedno, shednon);

        streg = 6*shedno+4;
        lsreg = streg + 5;
        ByteToStr(streg, stregn);
        ByteToStr(lsreg, lsregn);
     }

      void shedrelay(){
              rang =0;
              for(x=streg; x<=lsreg; x++){
                regval[rang] = EEPROM_Read(x);
                Delay_ms(100);
                if(rang < 6){
                rang++;
                }
              }
              reg1 =  regval[0]+sttime+editno1;
              reg2 =  regval[1]+sttime+editno2;
              reg3 =  regval[2]+sttime+editno3;
              reg4 =  regval[3]+sttime+editno4;
              reg5 =  regval[4]+sttime+editno5;
              reg6 =  regval[5]+sttime+editno6;
              Wordtostr(reg1,ntrel1);
              Wordtostr(reg2,ntrel2);
              Wordtostr(reg3,ntrel3);
              Wordtostr(reg4,ntrel4);
              Wordtostr(reg5,ntrel5);
              Wordtostr(reg6,ntrel6);
     }
      void shedselectdis(){
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
              Lcd_Out(1,1,"Next Shedule: S");
              Lcd_Out(1,16,shednon);
              Lcd_Out(2,1,"R1:");
              Lcd_Out(2,4,ntrel1);
              Lcd_Out(2,11,"R2:");
              Lcd_Out(2,14,ntrel2);
              Lcd_Out(3,1,"R3:");
              Lcd_Out(3,4,ntrel3);
              Lcd_Out(3,11,"R4:");
              Lcd_Out(3,14,ntrel4);
              Lcd_Out(4,1,"R5:");
              Lcd_Out(4,4,ntrel5);
              Lcd_Out(4,11,"R6:");
              Lcd_Out(4,14,ntrel6);
     }

     void editshed(){
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
                  Lcd_Out(1,1,"Edit Shedule: S");
                  Lcd_Out(1,16,shednon);
                  Lcd_Out(2,1,"R1:");
                  Lcd_Out(2,4,ntrel1);
                  Lcd_Out(2,11,"R2:");
                  Lcd_Out(2,14,ntrel2);
                  Lcd_Out(3,1,"R3:");
                  Lcd_Out(3,4,ntrel3);
                  Lcd_Out(3,11,"R4:");
                  Lcd_Out(3,14,ntrel4);
                  Lcd_Out(4,1,"R5:");
                  Lcd_Out(4,4,ntrel5);
                  Lcd_Out(4,11,"R6:");
                  Lcd_Out(4,14,ntrel6);
     }

     void relayssw(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6){
              PORTA = 0b00000001;
              VDelay_ms(x1);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00000010;
              VDelay_ms(x2);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00000100;
              VDelay_ms(x3);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00001000;
              VDelay_ms(x4);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00010000;
              VDelay_ms(x5);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00100000;
              VDelay_ms(x6);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);
     }
      void disval(){
        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
        findshed(0);
        Lcd_Out(1,1,"Shedule: S");
        Lcd_Out(1,11,shednon);
        Lcd_Out(2,1,"Count:");
        WordToStr(count, countn);
        Lcd_Out(2,1,"Count:");
        Lcd_Out(2,8,countn);
        Lcd_Out(3,1,"Steps:");
        Lcd_Out(4,1,"Temp:");
     }

    void main() {
      TRISA = 0b00000000;
      TRISB = 0b11111111;

      PORTA = 0b00000000;

      ADCON0=0;
      ADCON1=0X0F;
      CMCON=0X07;
      CCP1CON=0;
      CCP2CON=0;
      SSPCON1=0;


      Lcd_Init();
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
      Lcd_Out(1,6,"Welcome !");
      Delay_ms(2000);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      disval();
      EEPROM_Write(0x00,255);
    /*for(i=1;i<131;i++){
       EEPROM_Write(i,i);
    Delay_ms(50);
      }*/
      while(1){
          if(PORTB.B7 = 1){  //proximity count
            Delay_ms(300);
            count++;
            disval();
          }
          //
          if(PORTB.B5 = 1){  //proximity count reset
            Delay_ms(300);
            Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
            Lcd_Out(1,1,"Reset Count?");
            WordToStr(count, countn);
            Lcd_Out(2,1,countn);
            Lcd_Out(3,1,"Press Enter to Reset");
            Lcd_Out(4,1,"Press Up to Back");
            while(1){
              if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  count=0;
                  disval();
                  break;
              }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){  //up
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  disval();
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
          //
          if(PORTB.B1 = 1){  //settings
             shedc = 0;
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
             Lcd_Out(1,1,"Select Shedule: S");
             findshed(0);
             Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
             Lcd_Out(2,1,"Select Set. to Back");
             Lcd_Out(3,1,"Select Enter to Edit");
             Lcd_Out(4,1,"Select Up or Down");
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
             for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
             }
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
             while(1){
                if(PORTB.B1 = 1){  //exit
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  disval();
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
                  break;
                }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){ //up button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  if(shedno < 20){
                     shedc++;
                   }

                  findshed(shedc);
                  Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
                  for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                  }
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){ //down button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  if(shedno > 1){
                     shedc--;
                   }

                  findshed(shedc);
                  Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
                  for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                  }
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                }else if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  findshed(shedc);
                  shedrelay();
                  editshed();
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                  editno1 = 0;
                  editno2 = 0;
                  editno3 = 0;
                  editno4 = 0;
                  editno5 = 0;
                  editno6 = 0;
                  while(1){
                       for(ed = 1; ed < 6; ed++){
                           while(1){
                               if(PORTB.B2 == 1){  //up
                                 //Delay_ms(300);
                                 if(ed ==1){
                                    editno1++;
                                 }else if(ed ==2){
                                    editno2++;
                                 }else if(ed ==3){
                                    editno3++;
                                 }else if(ed ==4){
                                    editno4++;
                                 }else if(ed ==5){
                                    editno5++;
                                 }else if(ed ==6){
                                    editno6++;
                                 }
                                 findshed(shedc);
                                 shedrelay();
                                 editshed();
                               }else if(PORTB.B3 == 1){  //down
                                  //Delay_ms(300);
                                  if(ed ==1){
                                    editno1--;
                                 }else if(ed ==2){
                                    editno2--;
                                 }else if(ed ==3){
                                    editno3--;
                                 }else if(ed ==4){
                                    editno4--;
                                 }else if(ed ==5){
                                    editno5--;
                                 }else if(ed ==6){
                                    editno6--;
                                 }
                                 findshed(shedc);
                                 shedrelay();
                                 editshed();
                               }else if(PORTB.B4 == 1){  //enter
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 //Delay_ms(300); //POINT A
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                 break;
                               }
                           }
                       }
                    Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
                  }
                }
             }
          }
          //
           if((PORTB.B2 = 1)||(PORTB.B3 = 1)){ //up or down
              shedc = 0;
              Delay_ms(300);
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
              findshed(0);
              Lcd_Out(1,1,"Runing: S");
              Lcd_Out(1,10,shednon);
              Lcd_Out(2,1,"Next:");
              Lcd_Out(3,1,"Press Up or Down Key");
              Lcd_Out(4,1,"Press Reset to Back");
              while(1){
                  if(PORTB.B3 = 1){ //down
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      if(shedno > 1){
                         shedc--;
                      }
                      findshed(shedc);
                      shedrelay();
                      shedselectdis();
                  }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){ //up
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      if(shedno < 20){
                         shedc++;
                      }
                      findshed(shedc);
                      shedrelay();
                      shedselectdis();
                  }else if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      findshed(shedc);
                      EEPROM_Write(0x00,256-shedno);
                      disval();
                      break;
                  }else if(PORTB.B6 = 1){ //test
                       Delay_ms(300);
                       PORTC = 0b00000000;
                       Delay_ms(100);
                       relayssw(reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5,reg6);
                  }else if(PORTB.B5 = 1){ //reset
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      disval();
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
          //

      }

    }
```

**Error:**

When I add one more line to this code for example `Delay_ms(300);` line then my Proteus Simulation and real practical both not working. But *program memory not full in IC*. IC is *resetting*.

[image: memo]

Proteus Simulation gives me following error message *continuously*.

> [PIC18 STACK] PC=0x09BC. Stack overflow is forcing device reset. [U1]

I think this is not Nested Calls Limitations error because this code does not have more function calls than recommended function calls.

> mikroC PRO for PIC limits the number of non-recursive nested calls to:
>
> 8 calls for PIC12 family,  8 calls for PIC16 family,  16 calls for
>   PIC16 enhanced family.  31 calls for PIC18 family.

**Question:**

How to identify error points in a code and how to solve out this problem? What is `0x09BC` point.

If you want any other data to identify error please tell me.

This is Proteus and MikroC Code [LINK](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bZKpwmcPQUjTsokyqTyYQjPKwCO6d4lB) to download

**Simulation Practical:**

I did following practical but I can not identify error points.

This is data of without Stack Overflow error in CPU Stack and CPU Data Memory. CPU data memory store in last memory location and middle memory locations are free.

[image: without error]

This is data of with Stack Overflow error in CPU Stack and CPU Data Memory. CPU data memory store in last memory location and middle memory locations are free.

Also in CPU stack going from 31 to 0 continuously and that is change to `0x09BC`.

[image: with error]

EEPROM also have a lot of free memory locations.

[image: memory]

Comment: Can you simplify it to 2 schedules with 2 timing values.  If that works then either increase the number of schedules or timing values.

Comment: @cup EEPROM have lot of free memory locations. I will try if you want it.

Comment: 0x09BC is in the middle of your program memory. So have a look at this address. I guess it'a a problem with one of the break statments. There are only a few situations where break is really useful (e.g. switch / case)

Comment: My code is stopped at TRISA = 0b00000000; after Void Main(){ waht should be the problem?

Comment: Try with just the variable decls and main up to LCD_Init.  Remove all other functions.  If that works, add disval and add in code until disval.  Do it one chunk at a time: when that chunk works, go on to the next one.